# jquery ajax loading image not displayed in IE

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a page with links on the left and data on the right side.
Now when I click on the link I use jquery ajax call to load the data.

So, when I click on a link I use loading image while fetching the data.

code,

```
$("#linkData").empty().html("<div style='text-align:center;height:400px;margin-top: 200px;'><img src='loading.gif' /></div>");
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: urlLink,
    async: false,
    data: appliedData,
    cache: false,
    success: function(response) {
        $("#linkData").html(response);
    }
});
```

Now, This is working great in Firefox but in IE versions simply the data is getting replaced after success with the previous data.

In IE it looks like very sticky, please help with some suggestions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: is the image only not showing? or is the `.empty()` as well not doing its thing ?

Comment: able to empty the data but that is not getting viewed. Steven's answer solved my issue. Thanks for your time Gaby

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, do you mean that in the #linkData, you get to see the loading image again in IE?

Have you tried setting async to true?

Comment: By putting "async" to true, you ARE using Ajax. After all, Ajax is asynchronous. By setting it to false, the call is made synchronous (in other words: the page blocks until there is a response), which is not what Ajax is about.